# the right way to do this with BEM+ SASS

Tags: html, css, sass

I am using the BEM method together with SASS and I have a big doubt.

I have this HTML

```
<section class="section1">
<p class="section1__tittle"></p>

</section>

<section class="section2">
<p class="section2__tittle"></p> ...

</section>
```

This CSS :

```
.section1{}
.section2{}
.section1__tittle, .section2__tittle{
 // as both headings share the same style, I apply it to each other
}
```

Now, how can I replicate applying styles to both titles, following BEM+SASS?

SASS

```
.section1{
 &__tittle{}
}
.section2{
 &__tittle{}
}
```

Because following this structure, I have to repeat it twice

The solution is to put a shared class or is there a way in SASS to make a .section1__tittle, .section2__tittle respecting the BEM methodology? thanks

Comment: It depends. How similar are `section1` and `section2`? If they are identical in most parts they should not really form two different `BEM-blocks` and the differences might be captured with `BEM-modifiers`. If they are very different but only the title uses the same typography settings you should create a title-typography `mixin` and just use that in both title styles.

Comment: thanks for your answer, I will keep it in mind!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to select `.section1` and `.section2` at the same time and use the `&` to add the "__tittle" part.

```
.section1, .section2{
 /* styles */
 &__tittle{/* styles */}

 &__more-shared{/* styles */}

 &__blablabla{/* styles */}
}
```

That works because the ampersand `&` adds on to each of the parent selectors, so the code above gives you the exact same selectors as this:

```
.section1, .section2{/* styles */}

.section1__tittle, .section2__tittle{/* styles */}

.section1__more-shared, .section2__more-shared{/* styles */}

.section1__blablabla, .section2__blablabla{/* styles */}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, I will keep it in mind!

Answer (score 0):

If .section1__title and .section2__title  are equal, why don't you merge it into one class?

-html

```
<section class="section1">
  <p class="title"></p>
</section>

<section class="section2">
  <p class="title"></p> ...
</section>
```

-css

```
.title { }
.section1 { }
.section2 { }
```

If you want to add some different properties to .title for .section1, .section2, do it in .section1, .section2 like below.

```
.title { }

.section1 {
  .title { }
}

.section2 {
  .title { }
}
```

It's not repeating, Ok?

Thanks.

Comment: hello, as I said in the post, I would like to respect the BEM methodology and your answer does not. Even so, having a 'title' lost among hundreds of lines of code does not seem to me the most optimal or correct (the example I put was something simple to be understood). A person has recommended me to use @extend from SASS, do you think this is a good solution or am I missing something?